# Inserting vectors into a PSD

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, file-format, import

I want to insert some vector designs to a brochure. I have downloaded some vector designs from a site. But I am not sure how to insert it in to my file.

How can I insert vector symbols in to a PSD file in Photoshop?

Answer (score 2):

*File → Place...* in Photoshop...

or Copy and Paste from the vector's native application...

or drag and drop the file from your OS's file browser...

- [Place files in Photoshop - Adobe Support](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/placing-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something:

If you have Illustrator, you probably want to use it for checking what you actually have got and maybe for doing some tweaks, too. From Illustrator you can copy and paste the shapes to Photoshop. You can paste as bitmaps, smart objects or vector shapes.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using Smart Objects wherever you can.